# Attempting to modify old windows frame application - how to rebuild?

Tags: visual-studio, build, vb6

I am attempting to modify an old windows forms application that was written in visual basic. It's running on .NET 2.0, windows XP.

I have a .frm file with the old code, and I have made the requisite changes, so now I need to build a .exe again. I also have a .vbp, .vbw, and a .BAS file from the same project although they didn't need to be altered.  I can't seem to get the code I have into Visual Studio in a way that it understands.

I have installed Vis. Studio 2019 along with the tools for building Win. Forms, started a Forms project, and added the files to the project.

The .frm file begins as follows:

```
VERSION 5.00
Object = "{F9043C88-F6F2-101A-A3C9-08002B2F49FB}#1.2#0"; "Comdlg32.ocx"
Begin VB.Form Temperature_Control 
   ClientHeight    =   8910
   ClientLeft      =   1125
   ClientTop       =   3045
   ClientWidth     =   13830
   BeginProperty Font 
      Name            =   "Tahoma"
      Size            =   15.75
      Charset         =   0
      Weight          =   700
      Underline       =   0   'False
      Italic          =   0   'False
      Strikethrough   =   0   'False
   EndProperty
   LinkTopic       =   "Form1"
   ScaleHeight     =   8910
   ScaleWidth      =   13830
```

and so on and so forth. About 1200 lines of GUI stuff like this, then declarations and the actual subroutines.

Right now thousands of errors are throwing, as though it's not interpreting the code properly at all. Maybe it was written in an older vb version that I need to somehow enable? The first error thrown is this one:

"Statement cannot appear outside a method body"

EDIT 1: This is indeed VB6. I wasn't aware that I can't compiled this in a newer version of Visual Studio, so I moved to an older version. I am now able to build the .exe.

However, the .exe will not run. It throws an Error 76 (Path not found). I'm back to trying to find out what's going on. Everything seems in order on the compiler side of things except the .exe isn't working.

Comment: Looks like VB6 to me.

Comment: It's possible that it is - this code was operating in line with a FORTRAN application, which tells you how old it might be. Does this mean I can't rebuild this application with VS2019?

Comment: VS2019 will not rebuild the app.  You have 3 choices:  convert with a 3rd party tool, rewrite in VB.NET or a language of your choice, or buy and install VB6.

Comment: That's MSForms, the COM ancestor of WinForms (.NET). If you want to build this project, you'll need Visual Studio 6.0 (with the last service pack, I don't recall which one it was). If you don't have VS 6.0, then you can't build it, you need to rewrite the whole thing.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon That would be Service Pack 6.

Comment: I have to say "they didn't need to be altered" is rather worrying, since VB.NET and VB6 are radically different languages - starting with the default access modifiers (`Public` in VB6, `Private` in VB.NET) and parameter modifiers (`ByRef` in VB6, `ByVal` in VB.NET) - if it compiles, then it's glorified VB6, not VB.NET, and it's likely a disaster... I'd start by specifying `Option Strict On` at the top of every module (along with `Option Explicit`), and removing `Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic` so that VB6 functions like `MsgBox` and `InStr` can be flagged and replaced with actual .NET code.

Comment: Thanks to everyone. @BrianMStafford was correct - this is VB6. Luckily we have a machine with VB6 which I am using to compile the code. There is now a new and more exciting issue in which the compiled executable does not run - it throws a "Path not found" Error 76.

Comment: Instead of using the compiled EXE, try running the code in Debug mode (just press F5 or Start button) and execution should break at that error. You can figure out your error from there. You can use the Immediate (Ctrl-G) window to check variables and evaluate statements.

Comment: Maybe you should totally rewrite this question (or post a new one) to focus on the problem you are actually having.